# Cut the prefix from a message - Error: .split is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

Code:

```js
if (message.content.startsWith("!test")){
    let splitedMsg = message.split("!test")
    message.channel.send(splitedMsg)
}
```

So I tried my best to learn from the internet and couldn't get it to work.

My point is to cut the "!test" from the message and post the version without the text. (the error is: `".split is not a function"`)

eg. that I said "!test hello"
and the bot should say "hello"

Answer (score 0):

`message` is the [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) object. You should call `split` on `message.content`.

```
message.content.split('!test ')
```

Note that I'm splitting by `'!test '` to trim the space at the beginning of the rest of the string.

```js
str = '!test hello'
str.split('!test')
//=>  ["", " hello"]

str.split('!test ')
//=> ["", "hello"]
```

Since the text is in index 1, you should send the first element in the array returned by [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

```
const parts = message.content.split('!test ')
message.channel.send(parts[1])
```

Or use destructuring.

```
const [_, text] = message.content.split('!test ')
message.channel.send(text)
```